# subset my df provided that each ID has >10 obs a month

Tags: r, subset

I am trying to clean my stocks' df and I need to get rid of the ones that have less than 10 observations per month.

Already checked these 2 threads:
[subsetting-based-on-observations-in-a-month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27074023/subsetting-based-on-observations-in-a-month)
and [ddply-for-sum-by-group-in-r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14035872/ddply-for-sum-by-group-in-r)

But I'm a noob and I cannot figure it out yet.

**In short:** Please, help me out eliminating IDs (Stocks) whose observations per month are <10 (for any month if possible). They are Id'd via the permanent number from CRSP (permno).

Here is the df: [Lessthan10days.csv](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mdjm4j7mqlc4003/Lessthan10days.csv?dl=0)

Thank you so much,

Leo

Comment: Instead of a big dataset, it would have been better if you showed few lines of your data and the expected output based on that.

Comment: I'll try to show an example right now then, thanks

Comment: Try `res <- df1 %>% group_by(permno) %>% filter(n()>=10)`

Comment: Do you need to remove the IDs which have at least one month that have less than 10 observations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could create a column 'MonthYr' from the 'date' column after converting it to 'Date' class.  Get the number of observations ('n') per group ('permno', 'MonthYr') and use that to remove the IDs ('permno') that have at least one 'n' less than 10.

```
library(dplyr)
res <- df1 %>%
        mutate(MonthYr=format(as.Date(date, format='%m/%d/%Y'), '%Y-%m')) %>%
        group_by(permno, MonthYr) %>%
        mutate(n=n()) %>% 
        group_by(permno) %>% 
        filter(all(n>=10))

 all(res$n>=10)
 #[1] TRUE
 tbl <-table(res$permno, res$MonthYr)
 all(tbl[tbl!=0]>=10)
 #[1] TRUE
```

Or using similar approach with`data.table`

```
 library(data.table)
  setDT(df1)[,N:=.N , list(permno, MonthYr=format(as.Date(date, 
             format='%m/%d/%Y'), '%Y-%m'))][all(N>=10) , permno][]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- read.csv('Lessthan10days.csv', header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: Nor the setDT nor the %>% functions are found in my R packages, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @LeoDelMar  Have you installed `dplyr` or `data.table`?

Comment: and you loaded `library(dplyr)`, `library(data.table)` before running the code? If so, can you show the versions you have.

Comment: @LeoDelMar  In some older versions, `%.%` may work, and instead of `setDT(df1)`, `as.data.table(df1)`

Comment: That's what I was missing, loading them, never seen it earlier, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just like to add that the next commands work partially:

```
library(dplyr)
res <- df1 %>%
        mutate(MonthYr=format(as.Date(date, format='%m/%d/%Y'), '%Y-%m')) %>%
        group_by(permno, MonthYr) %>%
        mutate(n=n()) %>% 
        group_by(permno) %>% 
        filter(all(n>=10))

 all(res$n>=10)
 #[1] TRUE
 tbl <-table(res$permno, res$MonthYr)
 all(tbl[tbl!=0]>=10)
 #[1] TRUE
```

They do not perfectly clean the sample, I believe that some NA values are counted as observations, so they might 'escape' the subsetting/cleaning.

Therefore I did it manually to be sure. A suggestion I can propose would be using just:

```
>tbl <-table(res$permno, res$MonthYr)
>write.csv(tbl,"tbl.csv")
```

And then you look into the spreadsheet yourself for cleaning obs<10 (for each year/stock).
On top of that, you can filter the NA values for Price, and erase the 5-10 stocks (ids) that present a couple of months with <10 observations.

Hope this helps a bit. Thanks again for your help!